# Can I make Chrome not periodically close-and-restart an EventSource (Server-Sent Events)

Tags: javascript, http

I am using an [`EventSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource) to receive a stream of events from the server.

Chrome browser periodically closes and restarts the connection, about once every 60 seconds.

Is there a way that I can suppress this behavior? I can control both the server and the client.

Comment: I think you need to change keepalive_timeout from nginx. But I am giving another error. Request working normal and I am changing another chrome tab and request going again